# How is a character's health determined?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension

This question may seem a bit dumb but I only have the sorcerer revised edition (borrowed it from a friend so that i could run my own game) but it doesn't speak of how health work. I tried searching for it over the internet but i couldn't come up with a satisfying answer.

Anyway what I wanted to ask is how do I determine how much health a character has and what are their dodge chances and how does soaking damage work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Sorcerer: Revised Edition* is not a complete game, it's a supplement/sourcebook for *Mage: The Ascension*. You'll need to get a copy of the corresponding edition of *MtA* to learn how the game mechanics actually work.

Comment: I'll try to find a copy but my game is tonight so i really don't have time.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu If you don't have *MtA*, you don't have enough information to run a game at all. Experience with other WoD systems can fill in some of the blanks, but if you had *that* experience, you wouldn't have needed to ask the question to begin with.

Comment: @Maiko You'll have to reschedule or play something else. Even if someone explains how health is determined, you're missing a hundred other rules you'll need to run a Mage game. You should postpone running the game, and borrow the main book from your friend instead of *Sorcerer* to learn the actual game.

Comment: I guess i'll do that. Thanks for the advises. I am normally a D&D player and when i saw the game i thought it would be cool to run a game like that.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu *MtA* is a cool game, and *Sorcerer* provides some interesting variations on it. However, you don't have the core game. In effect, you're asking how to play D&D3E from just *Complete Arcane*, without a copy of the *Player's Handbook*.

Comment: While not a direct answer, I agree this should be the first thing the OP _really_ needs to know. So +1 there, but... may I suggest you mention the pages where health and damage are discussed. Perhaps you could also point to the [Quickstart Rules](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/58433/Mage-The-Ascension-Revised-Quickstart) (which are free). Oh, and BTW: in the QSR, health is discussed in the "Combat" section (page 10).